# How to change "default" Blender used by Windows?

Tags: windows, installation

I have multiple versions of Blender installed: 2.78c(for a class I'm taking using the game engine), 2.82a and 2.83a. When I hit the Windows key and search for Blender, the default one that shows up at the top is 2.78, however, this isn't the one I'm using most often. I'd like to change this so that 2.82a is the default. I have already set it so when I open .blend files, it used the version I want, and yes I know I can set a shortcut for the taskbar and use that, but I'd still like to be able to change this.

Comment: Well, just search for *Blender 2.82*. The searching algorithm is not really editable, to get instant acces, pin apps to Start/Taskbar :).